# C/C++ Integer Operation

Tags: c, c++, math

I found by chance that

```
int a = (h/2)*w+ (  (h+1)/2-h/2   )  *  (w+1)/2 ;
```

is equal to

```
int b = (w * h + 1) / 2 ;
```

when w and h are positive integers (assume no overflow).

Can you show me why these 2 are the same?

edit : integer -> positive integer.

Comment: In general or for specific values?  How did you discover this by chance?

Comment: in general. and it's not a homework. I found it when solving a algorithm problem and comparing my solution with another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this is a math problem: (integer)/2 should be interpreted as floor. So, the problem is:

> Show that `floor(h/2)*w + ( floor((h+1)/2) - floor(h/2) ) * floor((w+1)/2)` is equivalent to `floor((w*h+1)/2)`

Proof:

1. h = 2k, w = 2l: (both numbers are even) ...
2. h = 2k + 1, w = 2l: ...
3. h = 2k, w = 2l + 1: ...
4. h = 2k + 1, w = 2k + 1: ...

A hint: `floor((2k+1)/2) == k`. You can **easily** show the equivalence.

For example, the case 4:

a) `floor(2k+1/2)*(2l+1) + ( floor((2k+2)/2) - floor((2k+1)/2) ) * floor((2l+2)/2) = 2kl+k + (k+1 - k)*(l+1) = 2kl + k + l + 1`

b) `floor(((2k+1)*(2l+1)+1)/2) = floor((4kl+2k+2l+2)/2) = 2kl + k + l + 1`

Therefore, the two equations are equivalent.

Comment: This is really overcomplicating things. Greg's answer is much more simple and straightforward.

Comment: This isn't my fault; Math is just overcomplicated :) I showed only one case out of four. :D

Comment: It's a little bit compleated but thank you for your elaboration.

Comment: It's simpler if you do the math before factoring in the floor stuff. Your expression is ` (h/2)*w+ (  (h+1)/2-h/2   )  *  (w+1)/2  = (hw + (w+1) (h+1-h))/2 = (hw+w+1)/2 `. If you consider that `1/2` is 0, it simplifies further to `w(h + 1)/2`, which you can then proceed to analize as Minjang said.

Comment: @laura, no, you're wrong. You can't simply factor the equation like this: `floor` and `ceil` operators does not obey distributive law as in /,*. It's very easy to make such mistake.

Comment: In my point of view, this is not complicated at all, just a bit tedious to expand the equation. Typical math problems have this amount of complication.

Answer (score 8):

In order to simplify your expression, you will have to consider four cases:

- h even and w even
- h even and w odd
- h odd and w even
- h odd and w odd

From there, and applying the appropriate integer truncation rules, you should be able to simplify to your second expression.

Comment: +1 for slice and dice to something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, the question says that it's equal and it seems like it when you test few even and odd values. But that's easy boring math, so nobody check all cases. I was also lazy, and, even if I am more a math guy, I did a quick computer check using few copy-paste:

```
bool diff = false;
int n = 100;
for(int w = -n; w<n; ++w){
    for(int h = -n; h<n; ++h){
        int a = (h/2)*w+ (  (h+1)/2-h/2   )  *  (w+1)/2 ;
        int b = (w * h + 1) / 2;
        if (a!=b) diff = true;
    }
}
cout << (diff ? "a != b" : "a == b") << endl;
```

And I found that it's not equal for w = -1 and h =-1, easy to check that then a = 0 and b = 1. This is how "nice simplification" often introduces new bug.

PS: To be fair, I am guessing that w and h are width and height, so they are probably always positive. But that was not specified (and, by experience, some other code may return negative width)

Comment: thanks for the testing. yeah I missed the condition that w and h are positive. I posted after this kind of testing actually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct mathematical question. Just prove the following:

(h/2)*w+ (  (h+1)/2-h/2   )  *  (w+1)/2 = (w * h + 1) / 2